# Google Maps Route bounds after route drag

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using `directionsService.route` to calculate a route between number of points.
On the call back, I use:

```
response.routes[0].bounds
```

So that I can invoke a second request to my server and display markers based on the relevant bounds.

This is working fine.

I have recently added option to set the `DirectionsRenderer` as draggable.

This works fine, however, in my attempt to simulate the exact same behavior of getting markers based on bounds, I need to be able to capture a callback on the "route dragend" event.
I can't seem to find anything on this. The closest I got is the `directions_changed` event, but the paramters on this call back are irrelevant.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the event handler for directions_changed read the new value of response.routes[0].bounds. It should get updated when the route is modified.

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure what I was on, going in circles around that I complete forgot to check just that.. :)